# Jquery not working properly in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

this is my code for footer.php in wordpress

```
<div class="col-fr col-space flink" id="a-1">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <?php 
$menuParameters = array(
  'menu'            => 'New To website', 
  'container'       => false,
  'container_class' => 'footmenu',
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>


  </div>
  <div class="col-fr flink col-space" id="a-2">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <?php 
$menuParameters = array(
  'menu'            => 'Most Popular', 
  'container'       => false,
  'container_class' => 'footmenu',
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>


  </div>
  <div class="col-fr flink col-space" id="a-3">
    <h4>title?</h4>

       <?php 
$menuParameters = array(
  'menu'            => 'Need Help', 
  'container'       => false,
  'container_class' => 'footmenu',
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>



  </div>
  <div class="col-fr flink" style="margin-right:0px" id="a-4">
    <h4>title</h4>
       <?php 
$menuParameters = array(
  'menu'            => 'quicklink', 
  'container'       => false,
  'container_class' => 'footmenu',
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>


  </div>
  <script>

var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo("#a-1");
$("#a-1 a").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<li></li>").parent().appendTo(ul);
});


var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo("#a-2");
$("#a-2 a").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<li></li>").parent().appendTo(ul);
});

var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo("#a-3");
$("#a-3 a").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<li></li>").parent().appendTo(ul);
});

var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo("#a-4");
$("#a-4 a").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<li></li>").parent().appendTo(ul);
});


    </script>
```

this script not work normally but if i add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to header.php file before

```
 <?php
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
```

then its work fine... so what wrong with my code.. i don't want to add jquery add again header. it's load by defult already. version also same.. i tried paste that code heaer.php but not work also tried to make one separate js file for this and load.. but no work..

any solution.. ?

Comment: I think you have added more than one jquery library. Then it should be a conflict.

Comment: Put your scripts inside `$(document).ready( function() { //... });`

Answer (score 1):

use `jQuery` instead of `$`

because most of CMS use [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: thanks. but do you mean like this

var ul = jQuery("<ul></ul>").appendTo("#a-1");
$("#a-1 a").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).wrap("<li></li>").parent().appendTo(ul);
});

Comment: @arjuncc.. it wordpress theme .. so it loaded many jquery plugins.. 




but jquery only one that its 1.7.2

Comment: This fixed my jquery event issues in worpress. Thank you